# Adding users to the specific group in Django

Tags: python, django, many-to-many, manytomanyfield

I'm trying to add some users, in my Django project, to my created before group, but I know how to add to the specific group which I know the name and it's not dynamic. I would like that when I select a specific group, already add the next user. The problem is here:

```
g = Group.objects.get(name= 'New')
```

What should I do to replace this and indicate this group which I clicked?

views.py:

```
@login_required
def choose_group(request, pk):

if request.method == "POST":

    cvs = get_object_or_404(Cv, pk=pk)

    p = Person.objects.create(name=cvs.author)
    g = Group.objects.get(name= 'New')
    m = Membership.objects.create(person=p, group=g, leader=False)


    return redirect( 'proj.views.cv_detail', pk=cvs.pk )







else:
    cv = Cv.objects.filter(author = request.user)
    cvs = get_object_or_404(Cv, pk=pk)
    mem = Membership.objects.all()

    context = {

        'mem':mem,
        'cvs':cvs,
        'cv':cv
    }

    return render(request, 'choose_group.html', context)
```

models.py:

```
class Person(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Group(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
    members = models.ManyToManyField(Person, through='Membership')

    def __str__(self):              # __unicode__ on Python 2
        return self.name


class Membership(models.Model):
    person = models.ForeignKey(Person)
    leader = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    group = models.ForeignKey(Group)
```

choose_groups.html:

```
{% block profile %}

  <div class="jumbotron">
    <h3>Choose a group to add:</h3>
  </div>          

   <ul>
    {% for m in mem %}
    <form method="POST" class="post-form" >{% csrf_token %}
      <li><button type="submit" class="li1"> <b>{{ m.group }}</b></li>

    </form>
    {% endfor %}
   </ul>


{% endblock %}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue i see here is that you are not sending the group name `m.group` from your html.
to do so, you must add name and value to the button element in your html (and don't forget to close the button element)

```
<button type="submit" class="li1" name="group" value="{{m.group}}"> <b>{{ m.group }}</b></button>
```

Then, you can retrieve this group value in your views.py by using `request.POST`

```
g = Group.objects.get(name=request.POST['group'])
```

Comment: THANK YOU VERY MUCH ! :)